# Не работает бот-лайкер на Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, pyrogram

```
from pyrogram import Client
import time

api_id = 22.....
api_hash = 'd5.....'
bot_token = '677.......:AAF........'
app = Client('my_account', api_id, api_hash, bot_token=bot_token)

# Список чата для реакций
chats = [-1002.........]

# Список реакций
emojis = ['', '', '', '', '']

# "Формула" для лайков - реакции должны ставиться на сообщения вразнобой. Конечно, было бы хорошо сделать это рандомом, но пока пускай будет так
formula = [0, 2, 4, 1, 3]  

# Время для реакций
times = ['00:31', '00:32']

app.start()

# Реакции
async def like_posts(chat, emoji, formula):
    try:
        async for message in app.iter_history(chat):
            if message.message_id in formula:
                await app.send_reaction(chat, message.message_id, emoji)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Произошла ошибка: {e}")

# Реакции должны ставиться в определенное время
while True:
    current_time = time.strftime('%H:%M', time.localtime())

    if current_time in times:
        for chat in chats:
            for emoji in emojis:
                app.loop.run_until_complete(like_posts(chat, emoji, formula))

    time.sleep(60)  # Проверка каждую минуту

app.stop()
```

Я пробовал множество вариаций кода, используя get_history, iter_history, но программа всегда выдает ошибку - к приведенному коду ошибка следующая:
Произошла ошибка: 'Client' object has no attribute 'iter_history'
Уже не знаю, в чем проблема. Бот, вроде бы, имеет доступ к чату  (как администратор в канале). Может, я использовал не ту библиотеку? Или в чем тогда проблема?

Comment: Вы пробовали использовать [get_chat_history](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat_history#pyrogram.Client.get_chat_history)

Comment: @gord1402 , я и так пробовал, но всё равно возникает ошибка. Не могу понять, где конкретно. Как только я вроде что-то исправляю, появляется другая ошибка

Comment: Чтение истории доступно только для User-ботов это стоит учитывать для ботов сделанных через BotFather это не подойдёт.

Comment: @gord1402 ну а как тогда? я по всякому пробую

Comment: Теперь ошибка "Произошла ошибка: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send'"